# GtkIconView transparent while dragging

Tags: gtk

How do I make the GtkIconView transparent while dragging?

Comment: dragging one single icon or multiple icons from icon view .

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help.